# Why I can't see the image? (ImageView)

Tags: android, dynamic, android-imageview

I want to create dynamic ImageView, but it does not appear, any help?

```
@Override public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    RelativeLayout myLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);

    ImageView stone = new ImageView(this);
    stone.setImageResource(R.drawable.pedra);
    stone.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    myLayout.addView(stone, lp);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Does anything happen at all?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, It will help you

### main.xml

```
 <RelativeLayout 
       android:id="@+id/relativelayout"....>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

### In MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   private RelativeLayout rLayout;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {

       super.onCreate(savedInstance);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);

       rlayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);


   }

   @Override 
   public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

      ImageView stone = new ImageView(this);
      stone.setImageResource(R.drawable.pedra);
      stone.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

      rLayout.addView(stone);

     return true;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct but makes no much effect as it's art for art's sake. You create `RelativeLayout`, then create `ImageView`, then add `ImageView` to your `RelativeLayout`. And that works, but to make it show your layout have to be added to displayed hierarchy. So I'd add `RelativeLayout` to your xml layout file, assign `id` to it with `android:id`, then in your on touch do `findViewById()` and add created `ImageView` there.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to inflate your `myLayout`

Answer (score 0):

For some devices, put all images in the **drawable-xhdpi** directories as well.